# Same value, unknown type equality in reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I'm using reflection to retrieve the value of a property from an object. The value is an enum:

```
enum MyEnum 
{
    None,
    SomeValue
}
```

Which is on an object, and the property also has an attribute

```
class MyObject
{
    [MyAttribute(ExclusionValue = MyEnum.None)]
    public MyEnum EnumProperty { get; set; }
}
```

So when I get to the reflection part of things I would like to check if the value is equal to the `ExclusionValue`

```
// exclusionValue is the value taken from the attribute
// propertyValue is the value retrieved by reflection of the containing object, so at 
// this time it just an `object` type.

if(exclusionValue == propertyValue)
{
    // Both values are `MyEnum.None` but the if statement never evaluates true.
}
```

I've tried to cast the `exclusionValue` to an object so that they are both the same visible type

```
if((object)exclusionValue == propertyValue)
```

But this never returns true either. They are definitely the same enum value. Also, I can't explicitly cast anything in this `if` statement because there are many other properties in the object of all different types (not just enums) that need this same check, for example:

```
class MyObject
{
    [MyAttribute(ExclusionValue = MyEnum.None)]
    public MyEnum EnumProperty { get; set; }

    [MyAttribute(ExclusionValue = false)]
    public bool BoolProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

They will only ever be value types (no structs) or strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unbox the object you got via reflection to a `MyEnum`.

Currently you are comparing objects for equality, which tests for *reference* equality. They are not the same object, so it returns false.

This should behave as you expect:

```
if (exclusionValue == (MyEnum)propertyValue)
```

Or, you can call the `Equals` method instead:

```
if (exclusionValue.Equals(propertyValue))
```

Which will call the `Enum.Equals` method, which will do the right thing.

Comment: Edited - you can use `Equals`.

Comment: Awesome thanks. So am I correct in saying that the `Equals` method will check if it is a value type or reference type first and then compare by value or reference depending on that answer, whereas the `==` operator will only ever compare by reference (for an `object`)?

Comment: `Equals` and `==` are both overridable methods, so it kind of depends. Unless overridden, `==` checks for reference equality (except for value types, of course). `Equals` generally checks for value equality. `==` is overridden in some reference types (`string` for example) to check for value equality as well.